# How can I pass notification in only receiver side not on both side?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

This is my code of fetching data from `database`.

**`Model`**:-

```
public function fetch_data($v)
{  


                if($v != '')
                {
                    $this->db->set('chat_status', '0');
                    $this->db->where('chat_status','1');
                    $this->db->update('chat');
                }
                    $this->db->select("receiver_id");
                    $this->db->from("chat");
                    $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
                    $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
                    $this->db->limit(1);
                    $result = $this->db->get();
                    $output = '';


        $this->db->select("receiver_id");
        $this->db->from("chat");
        $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
        $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $result1 = $this->db->get();
        $count=$result1->num_rows();

        $data= array('unseen_notification'=>$count);
        return json_encode($data);

}
```

this is my controller

**`controller`**:-

```
public function index()
{ 
    $v=$this->input->post('view');
    echo $op= $this->Notify_Model->fetch_data($v);
    return $op;
}
```

and this is my ajax and view for calling notification in view

**`Ajax`**:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function load_unseen_notification(view = '')
  {

   $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Notify/index",
    method:"POST",
    data:{"view":view},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('.dropdown-menu').html(data.notification);
     $('.count').show();
     if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
     {    
      $('.count').html(data.unseen_notification);
     }  else if(data.unseen_notification == ''){
         $('.count').hide();
     }
    }
   });
  }
  load_unseen_notification();
  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){
   $('.count').html('');
   load_unseen_notification('yes');
  });
  setInterval(function(){
   load_unseen_notification();
  }, 1000);
  });
```

and this is my view where i called notification count:

**`view`**:-

```
<li class="treeview">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url('chat'); ?>" class="dropdown-toggle sample">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <span>Chat</span>
            <span class="label label-pill count" style="border-radius:10px;"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
```

now i just want to see notification on receiver side but in this notification shows on both.
how can i change the code to implement that situation. Please help.

Comment: Dont you think your data should bring current logged in user?
If that condition is proper, it will be executed at both end without modifying anything as script is execting at every X seconds

Comment: yes it is ok to current logged user but when i am sending message to another user the notification ping on both side. i want only ping in receiver side

Comment: at the beginning... set a var in js some what unique value... store user name in variable... and whenever you get response from the server fatch the sander name as well via ajax... use condition.. if user name is not same then notify ...

Comment: ok i will try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change in your model view because you are passing both receiver_id you have to pass sender_id and receiver_id too.

change to this:-

```
public function fetch_data($v)
{  


                if($v != '')
                {
                    $this->db->set('chat_status', '0');
                    $this->db->where("receiver_id", $this->session->userdata('id'));
                    $this->db->update('chat');
                }
                    $receiver_id = $this->session->userdata('sender_id');
                    $this->db->select();
                    $this->db->from("chat");
                    $this->db->where("sender_id", $receiver_id);
                    $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
                    $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
                    $this->db->limit(1);
                    $result = $this->db->get();
                    $output = '';

        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from("chat");
        $this->db->where("receiver_id", $receiver_id);
        $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
        $this->db->order_by("id", "DESC");
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $result1 = $this->db->get();
        $count=$result1->num_rows();
        $data= array('unseen_notification'=>$count);
        return json_encode($data);

}
```